# PostgreSQL conditional where clause

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

In my Ruby on Rails app I'm using blazer(https://github.com/ankane/blazer) and I have the following sql query:

```
SELECT *
FROM survey_results sr
LEFT JOIN clients c ON c.id = sr.client_id
WHERE sr.client_id = {client_id}
```

This query works really well. But I need to add conditional logic to check if client_id variable is present. If yes then I filter by this variable, if not then I not launching this `where` clause. How can I do it in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Check if its null OR your condition like this:

```
WHERE {client_id} IS NULL OR sr.client_id = {client_id}
```

The `WHERE` clause evaluate as follow: If the variable is empty, then the `WHERE` clause evaluate to true, and therefore - no filter. If not, it continue to the next condition of the `OR`

Comment: How can we use it for multiple values?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean? @Ulvi

Comment: I found the answer. I wanted to have multiple filters. I wrapped each of them with brackets and wrote AND among them.

Comment: for strings, we can equate with '' as well

Answer (score 1):

If anyone faced with the **psql operator does not exist: bigint = bytea** issue, here is my workaround:

```
WHERE ({client_id} < 0 AND sr.client_id > {client_id}) OR sr.client_id = {client_id}
```

Please consider that, client_id generally cannot be negative so you can use that information for eleminating the operation cast issue.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

I use spring data jpa, native query.

Here is my repository interface signature.

```
@Query(... where (case when 0 in :itemIds then true else i.id in :itemIds end) ...)
List<Item> getItems(@Param("itemIds) List<Long> itemIds)
```

Prior calling this method, I check if `itemIds` is null. If yes, I set value to 0L:

```
if(itemIds == null) {
   itemIds = new ArrayList<Long>();
   itemIds.add(0L);
}
itemRepo.getItems(itemIds);
```

My IDs starts from 1 so there is no case when ID = 0.